# Mariadb galera node error when joinning cluster

Tags: mariadb, mysql-cluster, galera

I am getting these errors when trying to join nodes to a master.

Ubuntu 14.04 MariaDb Galera 5.5.42.

I had this problem with rsync as well. No iptables rules blocking connections. Any help would be great with this.

```
WSREP: Failed to prepare for incremental state transfer: Local state UUID (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) does not match group state UUID (108c02b0-04b1-11e5-aab0-1b3efd0381b3): 1 (Operation not permitted)

[Warning] WSREP: 0.0 (): State transfer to 1.0 () failed: -32 (Broken pipe)
```

my joiner conf

```
[mysqld]
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name="my_cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://10.10.10.1,10.10.10.3"
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup-v2
wsrep_sst_receive_address=10.10.10.1
wsrep_sst_auth='*:*'
```

my donor conf

```
[mysqld]
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name="my_cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://10.10.10.2,10.10.10.3"
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup-v2
wsrep_sst_auth='*:*'
```

Comment: Do you have port testing which need by ?

Comment: https://support.severalnines.com/hc/en-us/articles/212426063-Firewall-ports-